# svn merging between two branches

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have two svn branches TRUNK and DEV_1. DEV_1 branch is created from TRUNK. I have made a lot of changes to DEV_1 branch and meanwhile other team members have made some commits to TRUNK.

Now I want to merge all the changes made by my team members on TRUNK to the development branch.

From the latest check out of `DEV_1`, I do

```
svn merge -r 17253:17330 --dry-run svn+ssh://user.name@svn.xx.xxx.com/dag/svnroot/core/xxx/trunk
```

The summary of conflicts is as follows.

```
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 19
  Tree conflicts: 2
```

I have saved the ouput of the svn merge command above in a file called `tmp.txt`
If I do

```
 cat tmp.txt | egrep '^C|^.C' | wc -l
```

I get `19`

This means that 19 files are showing conflicts when trying to merge TRUNK back to DEV_1.

My question is what does Tree conflicts mean?

```
cat tmp.txt | egrep '^A|^.A' | wc -l
9

cat tmp.txt | egrep '^D|^.D' | wc -l
13

cat tmp.txt | egrep '^U|^.U' | wc -l
524

cat tmp.txt | egrep '^G|^.G' | wc -l
3
```

I want to understand what the tree conflict mean before I remove the dry-run

Comment: Have you read [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html)?

Comment: You should use `svn merge --dry-run ^/core/xxx/trunk` if you have a recent version of svn, and you should do the operation on a clean working directory. If you do this, you can also try without `--dry-run`, because in some situations `--dry-run` reports conflicts, that do not occur during actual merging.